# Normalize it to 5th normal from

Tags: database, database-normalization

[This questions is obviously a homework question. I can't understand my professor and have no idea what he said during the election. I need to make step by step instructions to normalize the following table first into 1NF, then 2NF,3NF AND 4TH NF AND 5TH NF][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzlz9.jpg

Comment: Have you tried googling? There are literally tons of documents that describe the various normal forms and how to obtain them from an initial schema ... for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you show no research or other effort. [ask] [Help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you rely on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.